# Is there a way to replace text from a JSON object after it has been stringified?

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have some JSON data which contains some urls. I'm extracting these urls from the json by looping through the objects which works fine. The urls however have 'page: ' pre-pended to them which i am trying to replace with 'https://'.

I can't get the replace property to work and give me the same result each time.

I've tried using the replace() property in different way and am using the console.log to view my results. I've also tried to stringify the JSON as I hear this is a good thing to do in order to handle it.

Each time i'm still seeing the 'page: ' word and it hasn't been replaced.

```
function showTopArticles(jsonObj) {
var getEntries = jsonObj.feed.entry;
var stringified = JSON.stringify(getEntries);    
console.log(getEntries);

    for (var i = 0; i < getEntries.length; i++) {

        var list = document.createElement('article');
        var articleTitle = document.createElement('li');
        var articleUrl = document.createElement('a');
        articleTitle.textContent = getEntries[i].title.$t;
        articleUrl.textContent = getEntries[i].content.$t;

        articleUrl.textContent.replace("page: ", "https://");
        console.log(articleUrl.textContent);

    list.appendChild(articleTitle)+list.appendChild(articleUrl);
    section.appendChild(list);

    }

}
```

I expect the output url to be 'https://www.google.com' but instead im seeing 'page : www.google.com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` returns a modified value, it does not modify the original string.

You want something like:

```
articleUrl.textContent = articleUrl.textContent.replace("page: ", "https://");
```